# If I want social media icons that link to my site's corresponding accounts, is that better to do with a plugin, or manually?

Tags: customization

I feel like it's simple enough that coding it in would be beneficial, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Better regarding to what?

Answer (score 0):

What it sound like you are thinking of, would just require html/css, and not any php - I would just keep it simple and just add the code to a text widget.

There really isn't a right or wrong answer here, it is just preference.